# Itertools Chain on Nested List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists combined sequentially to create a nested list with python's map and zip funcionality; however, I wish to recreate this with itertools.

Furthermore, I am trying to understand why itertools.chain is returning a flattened list when I insert two lists, but when I add a nested list it simply returns the nested list.

Any help on these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

#how can I produce this with itertools?
c = list(map(list, zip(a,b)))
print(c) #[[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]

d = list(chain(c))
print(d) #[[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]

d = list(chain(a,b))
print(d) #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: _why?_ because that what it does [according to specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Why do you want to use `itertools` for it? `zip` in Python 3 is lazy by default. It's the solely reason why `itertools.izip` is no longer available in Python 3.x.

Comment: I think you mean to use  `chain.from_iterable(c)`. `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` do very different things

Comment: I didn't know it was done away with. I am just trying to understand itertools. In the meantime this works:                                                          `a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

nested_list = list(map(list, zip(a,b)))

flattened = []
for sub_list in nested_list:
    for var in sub_list:
        flattened.append(var)
print(flattened)`

Comment: I am not sure what your question is exactly, you are doing very different things in each part so not sure where the relation to each other is.

Comment: Are you asking how to use itertools to create a nested list from the two original lists, And how to use itertools to flatten the nested list?

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to answer your questions as best I can.

First off, `itertools.chain` doesn't work the way you think it does. `chain` takes `x` number of iterables and iterates over them in sequence. When you call `chain`, it essentially (internally) packs the objects into a list:

```
chain("ABC", "DEF") # Internally creates ["ABC", "DEF"]
```

Inside the method, it accesses each of these items one at a time, and iterates through them:

```
for iter_item in arguments:
    for item in iter_item:
        yield item
```

So when you call `chain([[a,b],[c,d,e],[f,g]])`, it creates a list with *one iterable object:* the list you passed as an argument. So now it looks like this:

```
[ #outer
    [ #inner
        [a,b],
        [c,d,e],
        [f,g]
    ]
]
```

`chain` as such iterates over the **inner** list, and returns three elements: `[a,b]`, `[c,d,e]`, and `[f,g]` in order. Then they get repacked by `list`, giving you what you had in the first place.

Incidentally, there is a way to do what you want to: `chain.from_iterable`. This is an alternate constructor for `chain` which accepts a single iterable, such as your list, and pulls the elements out to iterate over. So instead of this:

```
# chain(l)
[ #outer
    [ #inner
        [a,b],
        [c,d,e],
        [f,g]
    ]
]
```

You get this:

```
# chain.from_iterable(l)
[
    [a,b],
    [c,d,e],
    [f,g]
]
```

This will iterate through the three sub-lists, and return them in one sequence, so `list(chain.from_iterable(l))` will return `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]`.

As for your second question: While I don't know why `itertools` is a necessity to this process, you can do this in Python 2.x:

`list(itertools.izip(x,y))`

However, in 3.x, the `izip` function has been removed. There is still `zip_longest`, which will match up as many pairs as it can, and accept a filler value for extra pairs: `list(zip_longest([a,b,c],[d,e,f,g,h],fillvalue="N"))` returns `[(a,d),(b,e),(c,f),(N,g),(N,h)]` since the second list is longer than the first. Normal `zip` will take the shortest iterable and cut off the rest.

In other words, unless you want `zip_longest` instead of `zip`, `itertools` does not have a built-in method for zipping.

Comment: Very informative! Thank you for such a clear explanation. Also, itertools is not a necessity, I use rhinoPython a lot (which runs on 2.7) and many users use itertools to manipulate point3d lists. Thank you again. -Erik

Comment: @Erik glad t'be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `itertools.chain(*your_list_of_lists)`.  For example:

```
for p in itertools.chain(*[[1,2],[3,4]]):
    print(p)
1
2
3
4
```